# Compress a folder into multiple zip files

Tags: macos, compression, zip

I'm on mac osx.

1.
Is there any tool to compress a folder into multiple zip files ?

2.
Is there any tool to split a compressed zip file into smaller zip files (to open individually later) ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pass `-s` to `zip`.
2. `zipsplit`

Answer (score 10):

#### Splitting a directory

To create a split ZIP archive on OS X, you would use

```
zip -s <size> -r <out> <in>
```

Where `size` is a number followed by `k, m` or `g`, e.g:

- 650m
- 180k
- 1g

`out` is the name of the output files without the suffix and `in` is the directory you want to compress.

#### Splitting a ZIP file

```
zipsplit -n <size> <in>
```

Where `size` is the maximum size in bytes of the file to create and `in` is the input ZIP file. Note that it doesn't work when there is a file larger than `size` contained within the original ZIP file.