# Creating multiple ZIP files based on a size limit

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compress a folder into multiple zip files](https://superuser.com/questions/272659/compress-a-folder-into-multiple-zip-files)

Say I've got a folder 10 GB in size. I want to compress it into zip files of no more than 500 MB each, as many zip files as that takes.

Is there an easy way to do this without writing my own script?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a utility that will create *individually decompressible* zip files of no more than 500MB I guess you need to write your own script.

However, if you are looking for a utility that will create a 'volume set' of zip/rar/etc file of a certain size e.g. 500MB then you can consider p7zip (http://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/, available for mac)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use winrar or splitter and merger, or are you restricted to winzip?
Have a look at http://www.astahost.com/info.php/how-compress-one-file-into-several-parts_t3927.html.

Personally, I use winrar and it works great.

EDIT: Just realised you are on OSX, try this maybe: http://homepage.mac.com/pnoriega/unrar.html

Same principles.

j

Comment: note unrarx does not compress files...